# URL patterns in Django 2

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-2.0

I just have started my first project by using Django 2.0 in which I need to define a URL in a way as:
`http://localhost:8000/navigator?search_term=arrow`

But I couldn't know how to define a string parameter for a URL in Django 2.0

Here's what I have tried:

**From ulrs.py:**

```
from Django.URLs import path from. import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('navigator/<str:search_term>', views.GhNavigator, name='navigator'),

]
```

Any help?

Comment: It doesn't matter which version of Django you use, query string values are still not part of the URL.

Comment: Hi @DanielRoseman, this is not actually a query string, I just need to grab a search term from the user to use it for Github API.

Comment: That is exactly what a querystring is.

Comment: So, is there any way I can get a string from users in a url?

Comment: Well it is part of the `GET` parameters.

Comment: yes, it's the part of the GET.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no need to define query params in URL. Below url is enough to work.

```
path('navigator/', views.GhNavigator, name='navigator')
```

Let you called URL http://localhost:8000/navigator/?search_term=arrow then you can get search_term by `request.GET.get('search_term')`.

Answer (score 0):

**Request:** GET

```
http://localhost:8000/navigator?search_term=arrow
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('navigator/', views.GhNavigator, name='navigator'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
search_term = request.GET.get('search_term', None)
```